# What is the wheel base distance of the create2?

Tags: irobot-create, roomba

What is the wheel base distance that should be used for the create2 to calculate angle? I have seen 230.8mm in code samples but the manual seems to indicate 235.0 mm.

Answer (score 3):

The [OI Spec](http://www.irobotweb.com/%7E/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf?la=en) indicates a wheel base distance of 235.00mm. The wheels are 15.2mm wide, so 230.8mm would be the distance between the inward-facing sides of the wheels. Kinematics should be measured from the centers of wheels, so the 230.8mm figure is probably incorrect (unless there is something else accounting for the discrepancy in the code or the Roomba's mechanics).